# how to trigger click react-hook-form controller

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

There is an rhf element that opens file browser when click on it. I need to call this event from parent with press enter, within onKeyDown

Component

```
const FileImput = () => {

  const { control } = useForm({ shouldUnregister: false })

    return (
           <div
              tabIndex={0}
              onKeyDown={e => {
                if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                  // call Conroller element click here..
                }
              }}
            >
              <Controller
                control={control}
                render={({ value }) => (
                  <FileKeeper />
                )}
                name="photo"
                defaultValue=""
              />
            </div>
)}
```

Comment: could you include your `FileKeeper` ? or if it's a component from another package tell us which package you are using.

Comment: its material-ui package, import { Avatar as MaterialAvatar } from '@material-ui/core'